# AES 128 ECB Decrypting in .net C#

Tags: c#, .net, aes, encryption, ecb

For my new project I have to decrypt some files that have been previously encrypted by somebody else.

The information I have so far, is :
"The encryption is based on Advanced Encryption Standard (AES) Algorithm aes-128-ecb",
the decryption key, 32 characters long (43783C6 ...),
and about 10 encrypted files to test.

Is that enough to be able to decrypt the files ?

Because I've tried several decryption softwares and code samples, and none of them have been able to decrypt the files ...

Am I missing something ??

Thx :)

Comment: Your decryption key is probably 128 bits long (32 hex digits).  Treating it as 32 ASCII characters will give you an incorrect key.  Think of it as 0x43783C6...

Answer (score 2):

regardless of the desired implementation language, you are missing the information about the padding-scheme that was applied to the plaintext, or the information that no padding was used

additionally ecb mode should be avoided for security reasons (see [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation#Electronic_codebook_.28ECB.29))

Comment: Thanks. I'll try to get information about padding. Yes I know that ecb should be avoided, but unfortunately we do not have the authority to choose ...